# Spring AOP invoking some methods around Abstract method of Abstract class

Tags: aspectj

I have an abstract class like

```
public abstract class EventHandler<T> {
  public <T> void preProcess(Message<T> message) {
    // do some pre-processing with the Message
  }

  protected abstract void handleEvent(Message<T> message) throws Exception;

  public <T> void postProcess(Message<T> message) {
    // do some post-processing with the Message
  }
}
```

There are concrete classes which are extending from this Class.
I want to be able to invoke the preProcess() and postProcess() methods in the Abstract class using an @Around aspect when the handleEvent method is invoked on the concrete class.

I am trying to define the aspect like below

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class SomeAspect {

  @Around(value = "execution(* com.handler.EventHandler+.handleEvent(..)))")
  public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) {
    1. invoke preProcess

    2. invoke the join point

    3. invoke postProcess 
  }
}
```

How do i achieve what i am looking for?

**Update**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SomeAspect {
  private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TenantAspect.class);

  @Around(value = "execution(* com.handler.EventHandler+.handleEvent(..))) && within(com.handler..*) && this(eventHandler) && args(message))")
  public void around(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, EventHandler<Object> eventHandler, Message<Object> message) {

  }
}
```

Tried the above and compiler gives Unbound Pointcut Parameter for eventHandler and message

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @JArgente I am looking for a way to implement this scenario. I havent tried anything yet

Comment: Copying the comment for quick reference : an additional closing bracket `)` in the pointcut . `handleEvent(..)))` , which OP confirmed as a typo . correct one would be `@Around(value = "execution(* com.handler.EventHandler+.handleEvent(..)) && within(com.handler..*) && this(eventHandler) && args(message))")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Aspect can do the same.

**Explanation**

`execution(* com.handler.EventHandler+.handleEvent(..))` - execution of a method named `handleEvent` which is in a subtype of `EventHandler`

[Designators](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators)

`within(com.handler..*)` - A scoping desginator to advice classes within the given package

[Passing parameters to advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params-passing)

`this(eventHandler)`  - the object executing the method. `target()` may also be used

`args(message)`       - argument passed at runtime

**Notes**

An aspect be better annotated with `@Component` and `@Configuration` be used for configurations.

`within` added to narrow the scope to advice.Please modify as needed

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class EventHandlerAspect {

        @Around(value = "execution(* com.handler.EventHandler+.handleEvent(..)) "
        + "&& within(com.handler..*) "
        + "&& this(eventHandler) "
        + "&& args(message))")
       public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, 
        EventHandler<Object> eventHandler,
        Message<Object> message) throws Throwable {
            Object obj = null;
           // 1. invoke preProcess
            eventHandler.preProcess(message);
            try {
                // 2. invoke the join point
                obj = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
            } finally {
                // 3. invoke postProcess
                eventHandler.postProcess(message);
            }
            return obj;
         }
      }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting Unbound Pointcut Parameter evenHandler and Unbound Pointcut Parameter message. I am defining the Aspect in a different package than the EventHandler and also the Message class is coming from a third party dependency

Comment: Can you also explain the PointCut expression?

Comment: Could you try removing the `within` designator ?

Comment: The parameter names provided in your advice method and pointcut , are there are any mismatch ? Could you please share the updated code ?

Comment: Updated the question with the suggested changes

Comment: an additional closing bracket `)` in the pointcut ? `handleEvent(..)))` is that a typo or original code ? correct one would be `@Around(value = "execution(* com.handler.EventHandler+.handleEvent(..)) && within(com.handler..*) && this(eventHandler) && args(message))")`

Comment: I assume you were able to advice the method and there are no further queries on this?

Comment: does this work only for JDK Dynamic Proxies? I have a component which extends from EventHandler and the aspect doesn't seem to be working on that

Comment: It should work for both proxies ( JDK & CGLIB ) . If the aspect is not triggered , the common cause is an internal method call . Could you please check if that is the case ? If not could you please share the details on the error / scenario

Comment: Also if the aspect worked in one case it should advice for any method matching the pointcut expression.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by internal method call? The handleEvent on the extending class is actually triggered through an annotation (@StreamListener to be exact which is from spring cloud stream library)

Comment: Actually i havent tested that it worked by invoking my test. I am just seeing that its not getting invoked.

Comment: I am running this without the within Designator.

Comment: Scope designator is to make the aspect performant. The aspect works for the example you have shared in the question and it is tested locally before answering. You will need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on your current problem. If your application is not spring boot , have you enabled AOP through annotation `@EnableAspectJProxy` ?

Comment: Let me look for options to see how to share the code i am using.  Will post an update

Answer (score 0):

You can get the target object directly from the proceedingJoinPoint as follows:

```
((TestClass<Integer>) proceedingJoinPoint.getTarget()).preProcess(message);
 //or
((TestClass<Object>) proceedingJoinPoint.getTarget()).preProcess(message);
```

You would need to know the generic's instantiation type and have a matching message object of the same type.

If the message is in the arguments of the intercepted function call you can get them as follows:

```
Object[] methodArguments = proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs();
Message<Integer> message = (Message<Integer>) methodArguments[0];
```

If message is the first argument, it will be in methodArguments[0]

Comment: That's up to you. You did not specify in your question where message is coming from.  If message was a parameter of the intercepted function call, you can use 
Object[] methodArguments = proceedingJoinPoint.getArgs();